# Hcaptcha + 2captcha/anticaptcha in C# Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, captcha, 2captcha

I am trying to submit/callback after entering h-captcha-response and g-recaptcha-response with the solved token but I don't understand how I am supposed to submit it.
How can I submit the hCaptcha without form,button or data-callback.
Here is the entire HTML of the page containing the hCaptcha.
https://justpaste.me/57J0

Answer (score 0):

You have to find in the javascript files a specific function (like "testCaptcha") who submit the answer. When you find it, you can call it like this:

```
            captcha = yourTOKEN  
            driver.execute_script("""
              let [captcha] = arguments
               testCaptcha(captcha)
            """, captcha)
```

Could you please precise an URL where you have this captcha ? It'll be helpful to find this specific function.

Comment: Its from discord.com/register. But you dont get hcaptcha so often. Here is the entire html when hcaptcha shower up https://justpaste.me/57J0

Comment: Thanks. Could you try the following code:             captcha = yourTOKEN  
            driver.execute_script("""
              let [captcha] = arguments
               verifyCallback(captcha)
            """, captcha)

Comment: Did not work i am using selenium Chrome driver btw